# No ground wire in any recepts in my home 2 wire only

Tags: electrical

No ground wire for the 3 prong recept. Tester says open ground. I need to ground all the recepts in my house to pass inspection. What is the best and low cost fix? Thanks

Comment: GFCI protection is the cheapest option by far...

Comment: Note that adding a GFCI does not actually add a ground, it just avoids the issue in a code-compliant way. The only way to add a ground is to run new wire to each and every outlet. Also if the house does not have any grounded outlets at all it is probably reasonably old... 1960s or earlier. If the main panel has not been upgraded it may not take GFCI breakers.

Answer (score 0):

"Best" and "low cost" are contradictory. The "best" would be to run the correct wire direct from the panel (as well as correctly grounding the panel if it isn't already). The only "low cost" option would be if the panel is properly grounded and there BX cable running from the panel to that receptacle. Then the box for the receptacle should be grounded by that BX and a ground wire to the box would be acceptable.

Comment: "Only BX [aka AC] which includes a bonding wire or bonding strip may be used as ground." - "In general FMC or flexible metal conduit is limited to 6' in length when used as an EGC (equipment grounding conductor)." - "where flexibility is necessary after installation, an equipment grounding conductor shall be installed." –[Suitability of flexible metallic conduit serving as ground?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49785/suitability-of-flexible-metallic-conduit-serving-as-ground)

Comment: @Mazura Reference to conduit removed from answer.